# star-rating inside a box

Tags: html, css

I want to have a star-rating inside a square box. The above ~2/3 of the box is the "header". Below, there are 5 stars next to each other. They should span over the complete size of the box.

I already tried out a lot, but nothing is working yet. This is what I've got:

```css
.star {
  padding: 0;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

.checked {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="mybox">
  <div class="box-head">
    <span class="box-name">1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box-footer">
    <div class="rating">
      <span class="star checked">★</span>
      <span class="star checked">★</span>
      <span class="star">★</span>
      <span class="star">★</span>
      <span class="star">★</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My idea is: every star element should take up 20% of the width of its parent element. The font size should be big enough for the star to take up the whole space of its span size.

How is it possible? Everything I tried ended up in very small stars with big space in between that is not even controllable with the `margin` or `padding` properties. Moreover, I don't know how to adjust the font size correctly.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I think the only way (if vw doesn't work) to do that would be to use an svg / img for the star otherwise you would need js to calculate the size of the font based on the size of the span (css cannot do this)

Comment: Is it therefore possible to have an svg image of width 20% and tell it to draw a star over its full size?

Comment: you just put the svg in the span and make it 100% width, then it will always fill the span?

Comment: Ok. I'll try that. And how can I get rid of the space between the spans? In the Firefox debugger I've seen that there's some whitespace between them. I guess, it's because of the line break.

Comment: ah vw does work! see answers below.  But in answer to your whitespace problem - inline elements (span is inline by default) are treat like words in a sentence, if they have space between them, a space will be added.  You can either comment out the space, float the elements or use flex like in the answer

Comment: Ok, thanks. `display: flex` solved it well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I well understood your question, you should try in this way:

```
.rating {
  display: flex;
}

.star {
    padding: 0;
    width: 20%;
    font-size: 20vw
}
```

Comment: Nice! `display: flex` for the `.rating` class made my stars lie next to each other! `font-size: 20vw` however scales them relative to the viewport. This is a parameter, I can manually tune. Thanks! :)

Comment: I like this way better than my example. With flex, each `.star` could have `flex-grow: 1` to automatically handle the width percentages. That way he can add 1 more star and each would share the same width of ~16%

Answer (score 1):

Your current font size is scaling to 1% of the 'view width'. Traditionally, you can change the `1vw` to a fixed pixel size or responsive `em` value that actively adapts to the parent font. For simplicity, here is an example with pixel values:

```css
.rating {
  background-color: #ededed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 999px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 4px;
  width: 120px; /* parent width */
}

.star {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 20%; /* child width */
  font-size: 16px;
}

.star.checked {
   color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="mybox">
    <div class="box-head">
        <span class="box-name">1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="box-footer">
        <div class="rating">
            <span class="star checked">★</span>
            <span class="star checked">★</span>
            <span class="star">★</span>
            <span class="star">★</span>
            <span class="star">★</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks nice. After tuning the sizes, it yields a feasible result. Thanks!